# log result of java program that run from crontab [ Permission denied ]

Tags: java, logging, cron

I want to run the simple java program called from crontab. 
As I want to know whether the crontab is running properly, I want to print out the result as log file.

For now, I don't know the crontab is running my java program correctly or not.

Sample Java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("hello" + c.getTime());
}
```

Sample sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.6.0_31/
export JAVA_HOME;


for file in /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.jar
do
       CLASSPATH=$file:$CLASSPATH
done
export CLASSPATH

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java myTest
```

Crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh > /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.log 2>&1
```

PS: myTest.java, myTest.sh are all located under /home/vas/servers/tomcat/

Edited: include / in front of home.

=========================================================

Now I can see the log file , but it was saying that [ /bin/sh: /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh: Permission denied
 ] .

Comment: I dont see any problem here. You just need to configure and use a logging framework (e.g. log4j, Java's build-in logging) and it will create the appropriate log files in the destination you will specify. [Log4j Web Site](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to *overwrite* the log file:

```
* * * * * /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh > home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.log
```

vs how to *append* to the log file:

```
* * * * * /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh >> /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.log
```

(edit, based on your comment)

Can you try something like this:

```
chmod 771 /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh
```

And then do `ls -al /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh` to be sure you have set permissions correctly.

Comment: sorry. when I paste the code in here , I accidentally deleted / . /home is already correct for crontab.

Comment: but when I run uncomment the crontab again, I can see the log . But it said [ Permission denied ].

Comment: can you do a chmod on the .sh file? e.g. `chmod 771 /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh` (this changes the permissions to allow execution)

Comment: Thanks you so much . it works now. But one thing, whenever I run uncomment the crontab after I edit somechanges in myTest.sh, the log file is overwritten. How can I make the log file only append the new logs?

Comment: yah. you have answered my question . but as an addition, whenever I check the log file, seem like only showing one output (eg.helloThu Feb 28 16:18:01 SGT 2013 ) . I want to show the log file the output of everytime the crontab run the java app. Any further advice?

Answer (score 0):

Change `>` to `>>` in crontab and use absolute path to log file like this:

```
* * * * * /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.sh >> /home/vas/servers/tomcat/myTest.log 2>&1
```

Also you better use `exec` when running Java from shell script:

```
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java myTest
```